# Sort ListBox elements by size

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, listbox

I have a system in my `UserForm` with 2 `ListBoxes`. One on the left and one on the right. I've done the function so that I can pass any element back and forth between the 2 `ListBoxes`.
I wanted then to sort the `elements (strings)` in `alphabetical order AND by size`. What I mean by `size` is that a string with 10 char will be displayed after a string of 9 char.

Here's what I've tried :

```
Public Sub Sort_Listboxes(ByVal ListBox As msforms.ListBox)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp As Variant

For i = 0 To ListBox.ListCount - 2
    For j = i + 1 To ListBox.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox.List(i) > ListBox.List(j) Or Len(ListBox.List(i)) > Len(ListBox.List(j)) Then
            Temp = ListBox.List(j)
            ListBox.List(j) = ListBox.List(i)
            ListBox.List(i) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

With this function I get this result :

```
Element_1
Element_10
Element_2
Element_3
```

It seems normal if we take only the first part of the condition but with that second part it should work...

Note : I call the `Sort_ListBoxes` function for both list in both of my functions `click_right` and `click_left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the correct order that you are after is

```
Element_1
Element_2
Element_3
Element_10
```

then try replacing the `If` line with

```
If Len(ListBox.List(i)) > Len(ListBox.List(j)) Or (Len(ListBox.List(i)) = Len(ListBox.List(j)) And ListBox.List(i) > ListBox.List(j)) Then
```

... just amends the logic slightly to correctly handle strings with the same length.

Comment: Perfect answer, it's working like expected. i didn't think about a condition for strings of same length...

Answer (score 1):

A late post replying to your comment *`"No, I have an undefined separator which will always change."`*.

The challenge appealed to me to find this separator's position in order to make the original string values sortable via `Split()` based on prior match and filter actions.
Even if the separator  is *completely unknown* and digit lenghts range e.g. from 1 to e.g. 4, you are still able to sort by normalizing the original listbox elements *(e.g. from "Element_10" to "Element_0010")* via function `adapt()`.

*Methodical hints*

**ad a)**
My tricky `Match()` compares two symbol arrays, the first one consisting of the original letters+separator+digits, the second of archetypical categories where "0" stands for digits, "A" for any alphabetic letters". Omitting the third argument the `Match()` function finds the 1-based category position of any symbol within the given TYPES.

`TYPES` comprises five archetypes: 1-`'`, 2-`-`, 3-`.`, 4-`0`, 5-`A`. Each symbol is represented by its base symbol. **Example:** The slash separator "/" leads directly to the third TYPES archetype (i.e. `"."`),  so `chk` represents an array of category numbers per analyzed letter or symbol.

**ad b)**
As digits are represented as category 4, it's easy to get the separator's position as it is placed immediately before the first digit which itself is clearly represented by type 4; a positive `Filter()` via `4` allows to get the upper boundary of the remaining digit elements.

**ad c)**
Eventually it's easy to calculate a string concatenation including the original prefix (e.g. "Element") plus a "0000" formatted digit string.

```
Function adapt(ByVal s As String) As String
'Auth:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'Date:  2023-11-18
Const TYPES = "' - . 0 A"   ' Symbol types represented by lowest element
'a) check symbol types (digits occupy 4th position in types array, letters the 5th)
    Dim chk
    chk = Application.Match(Ch2Ar(s), Split(TYPES))
'b) get position of separator placed immediately before first digit (type 4)
    Dim pos As Long
    pos = Len(s) - UBound(Filter(chk, "4")) - 1: Debug.Print "pos=" & pos
'c) return adapted sort code
    adapt = Mid$(s, 1, pos) & Format(CLng(Mid$(s, pos + 1)), "0000")
End Function
```

*Further hint: it might be advisable to omit the separator in the sortable string by changing the first positioning to pos - 1 as follows:* `adapt = Mid$(s, 1, pos - 1) & Format(CLng(Mid$(s, pos + 1)), "0000")`, *so `Element_10` wouldn't result in the sortable string ►`Element_0010` but ►`Element0010` only*.

As close as possible to OP you might want to change your sorting procedure to

```
Public Sub Sort_ListboxColumn(ByVal ListBox As msforms.ListBox)
    Dim i    As Long
    Dim j    As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant

    With Me.ListBox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 2
            For j = i + 1 To .ListCount - 1
                If adapt(.List(i)) > adapt(.List(j)) Then   ' << using function adapt()
                    Temp = .List(j)
                    .List(j) = .List(i)
                    .List(i) = Temp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Helper function `ch2ar()`**

```
Function Ch2Ar(ByVal s As String)
'Purp: change a string to array elements
    Dim tmp() As String
    tmp = Split(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), vbNullChar)
    ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To UBound(tmp) - 1)
    Ch2Ar = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: I do agree on the fact that, this is the most efficient solution becauses it can catch pretty much every case (not ```/``` for example because it's not in the ```TYPES``` array) but not the most efficient. Ty for your answer which is decent

Comment: @EtienneNAMUR The **slash separator `"/"`**  leads directly to the third `TYPES` archetype (i.e. `.`) it is associated with. Types are 1-`'`, 2-`-`, **3-`.`**, 4-`0`, 5-`A`. Further hint: it might be advisable to omit the separator in the sortable string by changing the first positioning to `pos - 1` as follows: `adapt = Mid$(s, 1, pos - 1) & Format(CLng(Mid$(s, pos + 1)), "0000")`

Comment: My approach *does* catch other symbols/characters like e.g. the **slash** separator **`/`**, as `TYPES` comprises only five **archetypes**, each representing an entire category. So the slash is represented by the point archetype **`.`** (i.e. the 3rd element within `Split(TYPES)` array). I completed my post with the additional hints in comments. - Feel free to upvote if helpful and/or well-elaborated. @Tounn

Answer (score 0):

A UDF can be useful to ensure proper sorting.

- Assumes separator is `_` and last part is numeric.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sort_Listboxes(ByVal ListBox As msforms.ListBox)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant
    For i = 0 To ListBox.ListCount - 2
        For j = i + 1 To ListBox.ListCount - 1
            If FormatStr(ListBox.List(i)) > FormatStr(ListBox.List(j)) Then
                Temp = ListBox.List(j)
                ListBox.List(j) = ListBox.List(i)
                ListBox.List(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function FormatStr(ByVal sInput As String) As String
    Dim aKey
    aKey = Split(sInput, "_")
    If UBound(aKey) > 0 Then
        If VBA.IsNumeric(aKey(1)) Then aKey(1) = Format(aKey(1), "0000")
    End If
    FormatStr = Join(aKey, "_")
End Function
```

Testing:

```
?FormatStr("Element_10")>FormatStr("Element_9")
True
?"Element_10">"Element_9"
False
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for because there won't be always the same separator but nice answer if it would have been the case

Comment: I recommend unifying the separator before sorting to ensure the reliability of the results. e.g. `"Element-2">"Element_1"` is `False` forever.

Comment: @EtienneNAMUR a question just out of interest: do you have at least a well-defined set of separators?

Comment: @T.M. No, I have an undefined separator which will always change. That's why the first answer was the best in my case.

Comment: @EtienneNAMUR Comparing string with `undefined separator` is risky. eg. `"Element_1">"Element-2"` is `True`.

Comment: @taller I do agree with that but I know that I'll never have a case like this so no risks ofr me but don't take this as a justification for every case.

Comment: @EtienneNAMUR Fyi For the sake of the art I posted a late reply as the challenge appealed to me to find an undefined separator's position in order to make the original string values sortable via Split(). Additional benefit: different digit lengths possible.